# How to redirect to new HTML element/last HTML element anchor in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, model-view-controller, controller

In Laravel 10, I have a comment controller that stores comments in a database upon form submission:

```
    public function store(Request $request) {
    $formFields = $request->validate([
        'comment' => 'required',
    ]);

    $formFields['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;
    $formFields['upload_id'] = $request->upload_id;

    Comment::create($formFields);

    return Redirect::to(URL::previous() . "#comment-1")->with('message', 'Comment posted!');
}
```

On comment storage, I refresh the view with a success message. This is what the comments box looks like:

```
   @foreach ($upload->comments as $comment)
            <div class="single-panel panel--default comment-panel" id="{{ 'comment-' . $loop->iteration }}">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="user-col">
                        <p>
                            <a href="#" title="user">{{$comment->user->name}}</a>
                        </p>
                        <img class="avatar" src="{{url('storage/avatars/'.$comment->user->pic)}}" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="comment-col">
                        <div class="comment-details">
                            <a href="#">{{$comment->created}}</a></div>
                        <div class="comment-body">
                            <div>{!! $comment->comment !!}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
```

So each new comment will have the HTML attribute `<id='comment-COMMENTNUMBER'>`.

Is there a way to, in the controller's redirect, take the user to the HTML anchor of the comment that caused the redirect, or to the last anchor in the page (which is bound to be the last comment's anchor because of how I've coded the HTML)?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding a hidden `<input>` in the comment submit form with the value AMOUNT OF COMMENTS:

```
<input type="hidden" name="comment-num" value="{{ $upload->comments->count() }}"/>
```

And then in the controller I just take that and add 1 to it:

```
 $anchor = $request['comment-num'] + 1;

    Comment::create($formFields);

    return Redirect::to(URL::previous() . '#comment-' . $anchor)->with('message', 'Comment posted!');
```

Comment: This will not redirect to the correct comment, if your comments can be nested

Comment: @krisgjika luckily they can't! But yeah I can see how this approach can have unforseen consequences in the future if I want to overhaul the comments in this project. Pagination is another area where I can see this causing issues.

Comment: why not just use the ID of the created comment? no need to complicate things with counts

Comment: @krisgjika my `comments` table contains all comments in the website with self-incrementing `id`, but the `<id="comment-NUMBER">` HTML attribute is unrelated to the comment `id` in the database. The HTML id attribute numbers the comments specific to the post they're under.